# Where should I update state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where I updated state in my componentDidMount function. I got a linter warning that pointed me to this page:

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md

It says

> Prevent usage of setState in componentDidMount (no-did-mount-set-state)
>
> Updating the state after a component mount will trigger a second render() call and can lead to property/layout thrashing.

Where should I update my state instead?

This is my componentDidMount function:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        frame: this.state.frame + 1
      });
    }, this.props.interval);
  }
```

And this is my render function:

```
render(){
    let dots = this.state.frame % (this.props.dots + 1);
    let text = '';
    while(dots > 0){
      text += '.';
      dots--;
    }
    return <span {...this.props}>{text}&nbsp;</span>;
  }
```

My constructor:

```
   constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {frame: 1}; 
}
```

Comment: How about the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're not using `setState`, you're defining async operation that will use `setState`, this rule I believe is about sync operation `setState`, so if you're sure that first render will be before firing the interval, you can disable this rule in eslint config.

Check out this thread and comments from **@ljharb** https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/684#issuecomment-264094930

> Doing setState in componentDidMount will cause a visible render flash.
>
> However, when doing server-rendering, anything that requires a browser environment must go in componentDidMount, since that runs client-only, but componentWillMount runs on both client and server.

Comment: I see what you mean about the async operation. Even if I have the warning disabled in the linter, I get the following in my browser console: Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Comment: are you removing the timer upon `componentWillUnmount()`?  I can't see how you'd get that warning otherwise.

Comment: Ah.. I had spelt componentWillUnmount incorrectly.. :(. Marked this as correct because it seems legit to ignore the error and the other warning was because of my unrelated mistake. Thanks all